# Using Perl, search for word in array using hash maps

Tags: regex, perl, hashmap

I'm trying to search for a word within an array using hash maps as shown in the example below, but its not find it. The below code will read a book into the @bookArray.  Then, I want to search the @bookArray to find a certain word. The words in the book could be surrounded by other words without a boundary.

```
open( SEARCHWORDS, "< $encoding", $_folder . "searchwords.txt" ) or die("Input file not found.\n");
open( BOOK, "< $encoding", $_folder . "book.txt" ) or die("Input file not found.\n");

while (  $_ = <BOOK> ) {            
    push @bookArray, $_;
}
my %thebook = map {$_ => 1} @bookArray;

while (  my $searchWords = <SEARCHWORDS> ) {    

    if (exists $thebook{$searchWords}) {
        print "yeppie";
    }
}

#example of words in Book "I want to go to the store andbuy some food";
#example of search words "buy";
```

Comment: First, you need to `chomp` the `$searchWords`, to remove the newline.  Otherwise it won't match. Also -- are your words in the file one per line? (And, are there words in the book that are broken over multiple lines?)

Comment: there is only one word per line in the searchWords, and each line will be added to the bookarray (its broken over multiple lines).  I tried the chomp, but it didn't work.  Also, during the "if" statement, the $thebook is undefined even though the %thebook has data

Comment: I'm going to try using the grep method instead, because i think the exist is trying to match the entire sentence instead of a word in the sentence

Comment: Your book array contains whole lines, and those become keys.  Thus there are no keys which are individual words that you are looking for.  See what I just posted.  You can go with a regex to find a word in a line, but then you'd have to go through all lines and there is no benefit of using a hash.  Let me know what the objective is and I can add to the answer.

Comment: The `exists` checks whether a specific key exists -- so, yes, it is looking for a key that is a single word and none are, all are lines.  But `grep` is a filter, doing something rather different -- unless you want to merely identify lines that contain given words.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to identify the line that contains certain words, but that doesn't work using grep either.  The purpose is to find out if the sentence contains the searchword.  If it contains the searchword return the sentence.

Comment: seems the only way is the iterate of the book and return each line.  Then, use regex to search for the line for the word you're looking for.  This will allow me to return the entire sentence if there is a match.  It's slow, but accurate.  I was looking for a way to perform this task without looping through the bookarray using foreach

Comment: Yes and yes.  Added to my answer.  You still can break the whole book into a hash, what would swap resource requirements away from searching.

Comment: I added another solution, and also added code to implement the hash with keys that are words, where each word has for the value the line number on which it is.  Please let me know how it goes, and whether code explanations would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**   It has been clarified that the goal is to identify sentences with given words.

---

Each key in your `%thebook` hash is a *whole line* from the book. Thus when you search for a key that would be a single word, it isn't there.

A simple way to identify a line with a word, with what you already have

```
foreach my $line (@bookArray)
{
    while (my $searchWords = <SEARCHWORDS>) 
    {   
        chomp $searchWords; 
        if ($line =~ /($searchWords)/) {
            print "Found $1 in: $line\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This is inefficient, as each line is searched for all words, and after the book file has already been processed. But it may still be acceptable for a given goal.

Better turn it around and look for words in each line of the book as you read from that file.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

my $words_file = '...';
my $book_file  = '...';

open my $w_fh, '<', $words_file  or die "Can't open $words_file: $!";
my @search_words = <$w_fh>;
close $w_fh;
chomp(@search_words);

open my $bk_fh, '<', $book_file  or die "Can't open $book_file: $!";

while (my $line = <$bk_fh>) 
{
    chomp $line;
    foreach my $word (@search_words)
    {
        if ($line =~ /$word/) 
        {
            print "Found $word in line $.: $line\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This prints every time a word is found, on every line it happens.

You can also build the hash of words in the book, where each word is a key and its value is an *arrayref* (array reference) with line numbers on which it was found.

Iterate over lines and break each into words, adding them as keys. For each  key add that line's number (`$.`) to its arrayref value  . The number is added  even if the word is found repeatedly on the same line, which is a reasonable record of multiple line-occurrences. This is easily changed if not desired. We also store lines in the array.

```
while (<$bk_fh>) { 
    push @bookArray, $_;
    push @{$book_word{$_}}, $.  for split;
}

say "$_ => [ @{$freq{$_}} ]" for sort keys %freq;   # print all (long!)
```

The [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) by default splits `$_` by whitespace, and the `<>` operator by default assigns to `$_`. So `for split` iterates over the words on the line, doing `push ...` for each. The `$.` is the line number of the line currently being read from `$bk_fh`.

If the word has already been seen and so exists as a key then `push` just adds this line's number to the arrayref that is the value for that key.

Perl's *autovivification* makes this simple when a new word is encountered. When the expression `$book{$_}` is used the new word (in `$_` variable) is *automatically added as key*. Likewise, the `@{$book{$_}}` expression refers to an arrayref being the value for that new word's key, and so it *creates the arrayref*.  Then `push` puts `$.` onto it. We don't have to first create these manually.

See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for references and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for complex data structures.

Then you can check each word with your good idea of using `exists`, and if it does exist print the line from the array using the value for that word, which is the index of its line in the array.

---

*Original post*

You can break each line of the book into words and feed that into a hash, a big hash

```
while ( <BOOK> ) {        
    chomp;    
    push @bookArray, split;
}
my %thebook = map {$_ => 1} @bookArray;   # potentially very big
```

The split by default splits `$_` by whitespace, while `<>` by default assigns to `$_`.

Or, if you want to keep the array with whole lines as well, do it for the hash

```
my @bookArray = <BOOK>;
chomp @bookArray;

my %thebook = map {$_ => 1} map { split } @bookArray;  # potentially very big
```

Then individual words `$searchWords` will (may) be keys.  Also, the lines *must* be `chomp`-ed to remove newline. Otherwise some words will have it and some will not.

I'd like to add -- why do you open files the way you do? Is there something insufficient about

```
my $bookfile = $_folder . 'book.txt';
open my $bk_fh, '<', $bookfile  or die "Can't open $bookfile: $!";
```

Also, is `$_folder` indeed a variable that contains the folder name? That's a risky choice for a variable name.

Comment: My point exactly, I want to search for a word in each line and if it finds the word, I want to return the entire line.  The only way is to use the standard approach and iterate the bookarray and use regex to find the matching word

Comment: seems the only way is the iterate of the book and return each line.  Then, use regex to search for the line for the word you're looking for.  This will allow me to return the entire sentence if there is a match.  It's slow, but accurate.  I was looking for a way to perform this task without looping through the bookarray using foreach

Comment: @bigtime813 Thanks for clarifying that you need to identify the line. I added this as the last segment in my answer.  Note that the first part of the answer offers an alternative method -- to put words in the hash.  However, than you don't know the line, and this would have to be modified (which is possible to do, too).

Comment: @bigtime813  I rearranged the answer, with the double-iteration method first.  The hash method can easily be adapted to identify the sentence as well, let me know if you'd like to see that.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this and had quite some fun playing with `Term::ANSIColor`... will show you at the end what i did...

Now concerning the question itself:

**Step 0) The usually things to do, strict and warnings etc…**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $wordlist = 'search.txt';
my $bookfile = 'book.txt';
```

**Step 1) Read the wordlist first:**

```
open ( LIST, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $wordlist ) or die $!;
my @list = <LIST>;           # slurp the entire file in an array
chomp @list;                 # chomps each element in the list
@list = grep { $_ } @list;   # only keep 'valid' elements
```

**Step 2) Turn this into a compiled regular expression for re-use later:**

```
my $list = join '|', @list;  # search words seperated by '|'
my $regx = qr/($list)/i;     # turn it into compiled regex
                             # now this will look something like
                             # /(word1|word2|...)/i
```

Note1 : This is a case-insensitive match `/i`

Note2 : That regex will match a string anywhere, not just a word, if you want to only match a word use the following instead:

```
my $regx = qr/\b($list)\b/i; # \b boundary of a word
```

**Step 3) Read the book and print**

```
open ( BOOK, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $bookfile ) or die $!;
while (<BOOK>) {             # reads each line into $_ one by one
    print("yeppie\n") && last if /$regx/
}
```

Now, that is what You initially asked for, to print a happy thing, however, it seems you want to print each line:

```
    print if /$regx/         # if matches with $_ ?
```

So far, that is the answer for what you asked for. No horrible slow nesting of loops, no hashes no nothing, a simple `while`-statement and a pre-compile regular-expression.

---

***Now, lets have some fun and take it one step further…***

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants :pushpop);
my $OPEN = PUSHCOLOR . BOLD . BRIGHT_BLUE . ON_YELLOW;
my $STOP = POPCOLOR;

my $wordlist = 'search.txt';
my $bookfile = 'book.txt';

open ( LIST, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $wordlist ) or die $!;
my @list = <LIST>;           # slurp the entire file in an array
chomp @list;                 # chomps each element in the list
@list = grep { $_ } @list;   # get rid of empty elements

my $list = join '|', @list;  # search words seperated by '|'
my $regx = qr/($list)/i;     # turn it into compiled regexp

open ( BOOK, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $bookfile ) or die $!;
while (<BOOK>) {             # reads each line into $_
    s/$regx/$OPEN$1$STOP/g;  # wrap match inside $OPEN and $STOP
    print;                   # prints the (modified) $_
}
```

The three lines, starting with `use Term::ANSIColor` are hopefully a bit self explanatory, but just in case:

```
my $OPEN = PUSHCOLOR . BOLD . BRIGHT_BLUE . ON_YELLOW;
```

creates a 'opening tag' and 'pushes the terminal color / font changes' unto a stack,

```
my $STOP = POPCOLOR;
```

creates a sort of 'closing tag'. `Term::ANSIColor` knows what to do with those.

The tricky bit is at:

```
    s/$regx/$OPEN$1$STOP/g;  # wrap match inside $OPEN and $STOP
```

As you might recall, we wrapped the words list inside parenthesis, so the regular expression captures the word and stores it inside `$1`. Here we 'globally' substitute all occurrences of the word with one that has been wrapped inside our opened and closing tags. (Sure, that could be HTML if you change them at the top).

So, both files here:

`book.txt`

```
Hello,

This is a nice book about searching inside books,
which is an interesting topic when you want to do
that with Perl.

Read books about perl and understand how this works.

THE END

NB. I have added some nice colour options and print ALL
```

and

`search.txt`

```
book
perl
colou?r
```

As you can see, we can also add (small) regular expressions here. Be careful with the meta-characters, you might want to escape them if you need to look for them. Be very cautious with the `.*` for it is greeeeeedy!

Have fun!